# Prove $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ for all $a\in G$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove  $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ for all $a\in G$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $G$ is a group. Is it enough to just expand $(a^m)^n=(a^m***a^m)$- $n$ times. And then from here we can expand it a bit more to there there are $mn$ amount of $a's$? Or do I need to break it up into cases. I felt if I did I'll have atleast 3 cases and a few subcases. As of right now I have two cases one where $m=n=0$ and the other where $a,b\neq 0$.

Here is what I have so far.

New proof #2

> Case 1: Let $m>0$ and $n>0$ We will proceed by induction. We fix m and induct on n. 
>   Base case: Let n=1. We see that $a^m=a^m$. 
>   Inductive case: Suppose that $(a^m)^k=a^{mk}$ We shall prove $(a^m)^{k+1}=a^{m(k+1)}$.
>   It follows immediately from assumption that $(a^m)^{k+1}=a^{m(k+1)}$.
>
> Case 2: $m=n=0$. It is immediately obvious that  $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$
>
> Case 3: $m<0$ and $n<0$.  Let $m=-t$ and $n=-r$ where $t,r>0$. Then $(a^m)^n=(a^{-t})^{-r})=(a^{-1})^t)^r)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{rt})^{-1}=(a^{-nt})^{-1}=(a^{nt})^{-1}=a^{n*(-1)t}=a^{mn}$

Comment: We will need to deal with $m$ and/or $n$ that may be negative. Separate argument will be needed, since the definition of negative powers is different from the definition of positive powers.

Comment: well I was thinking even with negative powers we are just making sure the total number of $a's$ one side is the same as the other side despite $m,n$ being negative or postitive

Comment: Yes, but $a^{-1}$ is defined as the inverse of $a$, so there are a couple of lemmas to prove before we can use a counting argument.

Comment: Ah ok that is true. So basically I have extend the fact that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and show that it is true by induction. And then I can use a counting argument?

Comment: One can use the reults for positives to prove for negatives. Several cases. For non-negatives, can use induction on $n$ as a formal replacement for counting.

Comment: oh ok thanks. I'll do that and post what I got afterwards

Comment: OK. Am not planning to write out a solution, lots of typing.

Comment: Oh no I want to do this myself.

Comment: Oh yeah I posted my proof. I'm not sure if its entirely correct.

Answer (score 6):

> Case 1: Let $m>0$ and $n>0$ We will proceed by induction. We fix m and induct on n. 
>   Base case: Let n=1. We see that $a^m=a^m$. 
>   Inductive case: Suppose that $(a^m)^k=a^{mk}$ We shall prove $(a^m)^{k+1}=a^{m(k+1)}$.
>   It follows immediately from assumption that $(a^m)^{k+1}=a^{m(k+1)}$.
>
> Case 2: $m=n=0$. It is immediately obvious that  $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$
>
> Case 3: $m<0$ and $n<0$.  Let $m=-t$ and $n=-r$ where $t,r>0$. Then $(a^m)^n=(a^{-t})^{-r})=(a^{-1})^t)^r)^{-1}=(a^{-1})^{rt})^{-1}=(a^{-nt})^{-1}=(a^{nt})^{-1}=a^{n*(-1)t}=a^{mn}$

Comment: what if one's positive and one's negative.

Comment: Your inductive proof works for arbitrary $m$ and $n\geq 0$ - so you can get rid of the second case.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment
than an answer,
but
you nowhere say how you *define*
$a^n$.
You also do not say
if the group is Abelian.

My guess is that the definition is something like this:
$a^0 = e$
(the identity element).
If $n$ is an non-negative integer
such that
$a^n$ is defined,
then
$a^{n+1}
=a(a^n)
$
(or maybe
$(a^n)a$).
If $n < 0$,
then
$a^n
=(a^{-1})^{-n}
$.

To me,
this looks like the problem
of defining multiplication
in terms of addition.

I recommend
Landau's
"Foundations of Analysis"
for a bracingly rigorous
discussion of these and
similar matters.

Comment: (+1) for reference,  can you prove the main question in a set which satisfies all field axioms?

Comment: The thing is i have proved for real numbers $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and want it to generalise to $(ab)^{-n}=a^{-n}b^{-n}$. So i want to prove this(the op's question) entirely using field axioms, any help will be greatly appreciated ! : )

Comment: Are you sure Landau works with arbitrary groups? There are some shortcuts you can make in those basic proofs if you assume commutativity.